# Creating images in SVG and rendering them in HTML using Base64 encoding URI and JAVA

Tags: java, html, svg, base64, uri

I am trying to create a service that returns SVG. The **requirement** is that the SVG has to work in an img tag (script tag would be a bonus) and also to avoid JavaScript.

I have figured that encoding the img in BASE 64 and using it as a URI ,is my best bet.

Java Servlet

```
        String imageString = g2.getSVGElement();  // creates svg html string e.g <svg> blah blah</svg>
        byte[] imageData = Base64.encodeBase64(imageString.getBytes());

        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(imageData);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Response from GET request

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5v= ...
```

HTML

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/testapp/getSVG?optionone=1&optiontwo=2">
```

But when I load up the page I get blank img box. I know the base64 img is correct because when I do this . . .

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN22...">
```

It works fine. How can I implement this with the HTML tag above ?

Comment: Why are you encoding image into base64? Why don't just use binary data?

Comment: Because I didn't see this website : http://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/  -- Now I have it returning data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg+xmln  - where everything after utf8 is URL/HTML encoded - aaaand it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you returning a data URL from the server?  Just return the SVG itself.  There is no need for the `data:image/svg+xml;base64,`.

```
out.write(imageString.getBytes());
```

You should also make sure you are returning the right MIME type.  Ie.:

```
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml");
```

This lets the browser know that the response is an SVG file.

Comment: I return Base64 because it what I have used to make a graph work. If I create a static HTML page with <img src="<svg> .. . </svg>"> or <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg> .. . </svg>"> or <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg&gt; .. . &lt;/svg&gt;"> -  None of them work. But when I do base64, it works fine.

Comment: A base64 data URL is an appropriate choice for URLs embedded in static pages.  It is not what you should do when returning an a generated SVG from a web service.

Comment: Whether I send it in Base64 or Binary, I get the same result : the img tag (with src='urlA') shows a broken link but when I got urlA and get the response, put it in a src attribute of an img tag, the image shows up. For some reason when I inspect it, it says can not load image.

Comment: I don't understand what you just said. What is "urlA"?

Comment: Whether I use binary or Base64,I encounter the same problem; the URL does not work inside a img tag. If I go directly to the URL (GET or PSOT), it responds with "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xml ..." and if I put the data provided into a img tag, the image works! An example of the URL/urlA is the src attribute in the img tag of the HTML in my original post

Comment: Issue was that the response's content-type was being over-ridden by a resource handler. I am marking this as the answer as the Content-Type header fixes this. Thank you for your help guys.